# Почему не запускается демон docker в режиме rootless?

Tags: docker

*Linux Mint 19*

Установил docker в режиме rootless. Всё по [инструкции](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/), все команды выполнены, все нужные файлы на месте. Пытаюсь запустить:

`$ systemctl --user start docker`

получаю:

```
Failed to start docker.service: Unit docker.service not found.
```

Файл
**~/.config/systemd/user/default.target.wants/docker.service**
на месте.

Делаю так:

```
$ systemctl --user enable --now docker
$systemctl --user start docker
```

После этих команд докер стартует в rootless режиме.
Проверяю, добавлена ли служба в автозапуск:

```
$ systemctl --user is-enabled docker
enabled
```

Перегружаюсь. Докер не запущен. Причём:

```
$ docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///run/user/1000/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
$ systemctl --user is-enabled docker
enabled
$ systemctl --user start docker
Failed to start docker.service: Unit docker.service not found.
```

Чтобы запустить, опять нужно повторить всё вышеописанное.
Что не так?

Comment: `$ find ~/.config -name docker.service` ?

Comment: @alexandrbarakin, ну разумеется: $ find ~/.config -name docker.service /home/alex/.config/systemd/user/default.target.wants/docker.service /home/alex/.config/systemd/user/docker.service